# Can I use email to upload files into my Ubuntuone account?

Tags: ubuntu-one, email

It would be nice to be able to just email in info to my UbuntuOne account for retrieval later.

Answer (score 1):

No, as far as I'm aware you can't email files to your Ubuntu One account, however you can upload files from anywhere with an Internet connection and a web browser by going to https://one.ubuntu.com/, logging in, going to *Files* and then selecting *Upload file*
[image]